Fixed Buttons Relative to Container
I want to create  buttons that will stay at the same point vertically as a use scrolls through long tables. The purpose of the buttons is to allow them to scroll horizontally for the table. So I want them to stay in the table and only be visible in the table. Using fixed causes them to break out and be tied to the viewport. If I add the translatez:(0) to the parent container the buttons no longer move with the center of the page.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const tableContainer = document.getElementById('table-container');
  const scrollLeft = document.getElementById('scroll-left');
  const scrollRight = document.getElementById('scroll-right');

  let scrollInterval;

  function updateArrows() {
    scrollLeft.style.display = tableContainer.scrollLeft > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    scrollRight.style.display = (tableContainer.scrollWidth > tableContainer.clientWidth) &&
      (tableContainer.scrollLeft < tableContainer.scrollWidth - tableContainer.clientWidth) ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  function startScrolling(direction) {
    stopScrolling(); // Ensure no other scrolling is active
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
      tableContainer.scrollBy({
        left: direction === 'left' ? -10 : 10,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }, 50); // Adjust scroll speed by changing the interval time or the scroll amount
  }

  function stopScrolling() {
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
  }

  scrollLeft.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    startScrolling('left');
  });

  scrollRight.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    startScrolling('right');
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopScrolling);
  document.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopScrolling);

  tableContainer.addEventListener('scroll', updateArrows);

  // Initial check
  updateArrows();
});
.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* transform: translateZ(0);*/
}

.table-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 300px;
  /* Adjust based on your design */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  /* Needed for absolute positioning of arrows */
}

.scroll-arrow {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

#scroll-left {
  left: 0;
}

#scroll-right {
  right: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<div class="scroll-container">
  <button id="scroll-left" class="scroll-arrow">&lt;</button>
  <div id="table-container" class="table-container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
          <th>Header 5</th>
          <th>Header 6</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- More rows as needed -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="scroll-right" class="scroll-arrow">&gt;</button>
</div>




Sounds like you're looking for position: sticky.

@PhilB I don't want to use sticky because I don't want to have it add to the width of the table.

Then you'll have to use JS to control them based on scroll position. Sticky is the CSS way to do this.

@PhilB is there a way to use sticky so that it will sit on top of the content?

Maybe, although it's worth remembering that when the element isn't sticky, it has a position in the DOM. You'd need to be able to achieve the positioning you want first without absolute/fixed before sticky takes effect.

I hope below solution works for you (Run Snippet). I hope this is what you wanted.
I did the following:

Removed display flex from scroll container
.scroll-arrow - position:absolute, and add width:30px;
#scroll-left {left: -50px;}
#scroll-right {right: -50px;}

See below for more clarity.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const tableContainer = document.getElementById('table-container');
  const scrollLeft = document.getElementById('scroll-left');
  const scrollRight = document.getElementById('scroll-right');

  let scrollInterval;

  function updateArrows() {
    scrollLeft.style.display = tableContainer.scrollLeft > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    scrollRight.style.display = (tableContainer.scrollWidth > tableContainer.clientWidth) &&
      (tableContainer.scrollLeft < tableContainer.scrollWidth - tableContainer.clientWidth) ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  function startScrolling(direction) {
    stopScrolling(); // Ensure no other scrolling is active
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
      tableContainer.scrollBy({
        left: direction === 'left' ? -10 : 10,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }, 50); // Adjust scroll speed by changing the interval time or the scroll amount
  }

  function stopScrolling() {
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
  }

  scrollLeft.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    startScrolling('left');
  });

  scrollRight.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    startScrolling('right');
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopScrolling);
  document.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopScrolling);

  tableContainer.addEventListener('scroll', updateArrows);

  // Initial check
  updateArrows();
});
.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
  /*display: flex;
  align-items: center;*/
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* transform: translateZ(0);*/
}

.table-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 300px;
  /* Adjust based on your design */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  /* Needed for absolute positioning of arrows */
}

.scroll-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  width:30px;
}

#scroll-left {
  left: -50px;
}

#scroll-right {
  right: -50px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<div class="scroll-container">
  <button id="scroll-left" class="scroll-arrow">&lt;</button>
  <div id="table-container" class="table-container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
          <th>Header 5</th>
          <th>Header 6</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- More rows as needed -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="scroll-right" class="scroll-arrow">&gt;</button>
</div>



Thankyou

Like this (run the snippet)? Then you need to add position: absolute to class .scroll-arrow.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const tableContainer = document.getElementById('table-container');
  const scrollLeft = document.getElementById('scroll-left');
  const scrollRight = document.getElementById('scroll-right');

  let scrollInterval;

  function updateArrows() {
    scrollLeft.style.display = tableContainer.scrollLeft > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    scrollRight.style.display = (tableContainer.scrollWidth > tableContainer.clientWidth) &&
      (tableContainer.scrollLeft < tableContainer.scrollWidth - tableContainer.clientWidth) ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  function startScrolling(direction) {
    stopScrolling(); // Ensure no other scrolling is active
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
      tableContainer.scrollBy({
        left: direction === 'left' ? -10 : 10,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }, 50); // Adjust scroll speed by changing the interval time or the scroll amount
  }

  function stopScrolling() {
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
  }

  scrollLeft.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    startScrolling('left');
  });

  scrollRight.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    startScrolling('right');
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopScrolling);
  document.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopScrolling);

  tableContainer.addEventListener('scroll', updateArrows);

  // Initial check
  updateArrows();
});
.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* transform: translateZ(0);*/
}

.table-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 300px;
  /* Adjust based on your design */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  /* Needed for absolute positioning of arrows */
}

.scroll-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

#scroll-left {
  left: 0;
}

#scroll-right {
  right: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<div class="scroll-container">
  <button id="scroll-left" class="scroll-arrow">&lt;</button>
  <div id="table-container" class="table-container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
          <th>Header 5</th>
          <th>Header 6</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- More rows as needed -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="scroll-right" class="scroll-arrow">&gt;</button>
</div>




To improve on @Akshay's answer, I would give .table-container a max-height which is less than the viewport height and allow it to scroll both vertically and horizontally. That way your arrows stay visible as the table scrolls beneath them.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const tableContainer = document.getElementById('table-container');
  const scrollLeft = document.getElementById('scroll-left');
  const scrollRight = document.getElementById('scroll-right');

  let scrollInterval;

  function updateArrows() {
    scrollLeft.style.display = tableContainer.scrollLeft > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    scrollRight.style.display = (tableContainer.scrollWidth > tableContainer.clientWidth) &&
      (tableContainer.scrollLeft < tableContainer.scrollWidth - tableContainer.clientWidth) ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  function startScrolling(direction) {
    stopScrolling(); // Ensure no other scrolling is active
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
      tableContainer.scrollBy({
        left: direction === 'left' ? -10 : 10,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }, 50); // Adjust scroll speed by changing the interval time or the scroll amount
  }

  function stopScrolling() {
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
  }

  scrollLeft.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    startScrolling('left');
  });

  scrollRight.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    startScrolling('right');
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopScrolling);
  document.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopScrolling);

  tableContainer.addEventListener('scroll', updateArrows);

  // Initial check
  updateArrows();
});
.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* transform: translateZ(0);*/
}

.table-container {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 300px;
  /* Adjust based on your design */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  /* Needed for absolute positioning of arrows */
  max-height: 90svh;
}

.scroll-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

#scroll-left {
  left: 0;
}

#scroll-right {
  right: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum exercitationem dolores animi quasi odit deserunt, reprehenderit facere veritatis natus. Iusto error sunt cumque delectus rem obcaecati et temporibus cum ea?</p>
<div class="scroll-container">
  <button id="scroll-left" class="scroll-arrow">&lt;</button>
  <div id="table-container" class="table-container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
          <th>Header 5</th>
          <th>Header 6</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
          <td>Data 4</td>
          <td>Data 5</td>
          <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- More rows as needed -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="scroll-right" class="scroll-arrow">&gt;</button>
</div>



